# How the support vectors in the svmtrain function, converge the input data into a small subset?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, svm, subset, pattern-recognition

The input to the svmtrain function is a matrix with the dimension 151x22.

While applying the svmtrain function with the above matrix ( as shown below ), I am getting a structure. Inside the structure, there is a field named "support vectors".

The size of this support vectors is 42x22.

How does this subset gets formed ?

Answer (score 1):

`help svmtrain` says that the field `SupportVectors` gives a `Matrix of data points with each row corresponding to a support vector.`

So I guess that means that for your particular matrix, 42 support vectors were found.

To find out how those vectors are found exactly, you should look up some theory about support vector machines. Wikipedia has a quite extensive article on [SVMs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine).